# How are Bundle IDs supposed to work for multiple Apple apps?

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store, app-store-connect, provisioning

Here is the situation we would like to have: release two different apps by the same company.  Ideally, they could share login info across them but this is NOT mandatory.

Our current plan is this:

- One provisioning profile with the Bundle ID "com.wikia.*"
- App one (which is already out) would have a Bundle ID suffix of "app.GameGuides" so it's "Your Bundle ID" value is "com.wikia.app.GameGuides".
- App two (which we are trying to release) would have a Bundle ID suffix of "lyricwiki" so it's "Your Bundle ID" value is "com.wikia.lyricwiki".

**Is that how it's supposed to work or should each *app* have their own provisioning profile with the wildcard only for variations of the *SAME* app?**

Any help is greatly appreciated!

*[Note: App one (GameGuides) is already out, using a profile with the prefix "com.wikia.*" in the App Store & is also on the Android Market... and app two (LyricWiki) is on the Android Market & we're trying to submit it to the App Store but we are getting an error that our "Bundle ID" has already been used... not sure if this is an error on the "Your Bundle ID" or if the wild-carded Bundle ID can't be reused (which seems strange since it is wildcarded).]*

Docs on wildcard app IDs:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1713/_index.html

Comment: I'm pretty sure they need different App Store Distribution profiles, even if the underlying App ID is a "wildcard" (I also wasn't aware you could have a distribution profile with a wildcard bundle ID). However, I'd recommend against using wildcard App IDs if you want push notifications. The key to sharing login information is to not select "Generate New" when picking the "Bundle Seed ID"; pick an existing one, and then do the appropriate thing with `keychain-access-groups` in Entitlements.plist.

Answer (score 0):

Our company does what youre describing, com.wikia.app1, com.wikia.app2, etc. I would double check that you didnt try to submit it twice and make sure there isn't actually another app with that bundle ID, otherwise contact Apple to see why it's being rejected.